# Count the Number of Instances of a Word in Json String using Jackson Object Mapper

Tags: json, jackson

I'm using the Jackson Object Mapper (com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper) to parse a json string and need to count the number of times the word "path" 
occures in the string. The string looks like:

```
"rows":[{"path":{"uid":"2"},"fields":[]},{"path":{"uid":"4"},"fields":[]},{"path":{"uid":"12"},....
```

Does anyone know which API option is most efficeint for achieving this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To count total number of 'childs' inside the 'rows' root, you can use a code like this:

```
String inputJsonString = "{\"rows\":[{\"path\":{\"uid\":\"2\"},\"fields\":[]},{\"path\":{\"uid\":\"4\"},\"fields\":[]},{\"path\":{\"uid\":\"12\"},\"fields\":[]}]}";
ObjectNode root = (ObjectNode) new ObjectMapper().readTree( inputJsonString );
root.get( "rows" ).size();
```

If you need to get the exact count of 'path' occurrences, you may use the code like this:

```
int counter = 0;
for( Iterator<JsonNode> i = root.get( "rows" ).iterator(); i.hasNext(); )
  if( i.next().has( "path" ) )
    counter++;

System.out.println(counter);
```